# Bad delimiter in Bash shell

Tags: bash

I'm trying to iterate over few lines of bash script and echo all the non comment lines.

Within my loop I have the following command:

```
echo $line | cut -d" #" -f1
```

However the interpreter throws at me the following error:

```
cut: bad delimiter
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a string as a delimiter in unix cut command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857286/is-it-possible-to-use-a-string-as-a-delimiter-in-unix-cut-command)

Comment: The `-d` option appears to only allow a single character as the delimiter.

Comment: It's not clear what you intend `-d" #"` to do. `#` introduces a comment in bash, but it needn't be preceded by a space.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Actually it does need to be, mostly. "a word beginning with # causes that word and all remaining characters on that line to be ignored." So `(#This is a comment` -- because `(` is self-delimiting -- but `[#This is not a comment`. (Of course, the fact that a # is preceded by a space doesn't prove it to be a comment. It could be in a quoted word.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `-d` parameter to `cut` expects only one character. try using `nawk` instead for your example:

```
echo $line | nawk 'BEGIN {FS=" #" } ; { print $1 }'
```

Or to just print lines that don't begin with a " #", use `grep`:

```
grep -v " #" <file>
```

Or to print only lines that begin with a hash, or just white space and a hash, I'd use Perl:

```
perl -n -e 'unless (/(\S+)*#/) {print}' <file>
```

Comment: Any particular reason to use `nawk` rather than `awk`?

Comment: What if the line starts with `#` or tab character?

Comment: @Keith On my Solaris 10 system, awk did not produce the desired output. nawk did. The OP does not specify the system they are using.

Comment: @John - Agreed, but from the example the OP gave, their lines appear to start with a space followed by a hash. But I'll change my answer to give that option too.

Comment: @Warwick: Good point -- but I think Solaris is unusual in still having a very old version of `awk` as the default.

Comment: @KeithThompson Solaris `/usr/bin/awk` is broken and `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` should be used instead if GNU `awk` or `nawk` isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`:

```
awk '$1 !~ /^#/' file
```

Only prints lines that do not start with a `#` in the first field.

If you want to test if a string is a comment:

```
if [[ ! $(awk '$1 !~ /^#/' <<<"$string") ]]; then
    echo "'$string' is a comment"
else
    echo "'$string' is not a comment"
fi
```

Or another way using `bash` only:

```
if [[ ! ${string%\#*} || ${string%\#*} == +([[:space:]]) ]]; then
    echo "'$string' is a comment"
else
    echo "'$string' is not a comment"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, using `sed`:

```
sed '/^\S*#/d' file
```

This essentially says output all lines that do not start with any whitespace followed by a `#`. This is a modern version of `sed`, so older ones you might have to use something else for the whitespace match.